# pandas dataframe to coo matrix and to lil matix

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have following series:

```
groups['combined'] 

0            (28, 1)  1
1           (32, 1)  1
2           (36, 1)  1
3           (37, 1)  1
4           (84, 1)  1

....
Name: combined, Length: 14476, dtype: object
```

How can I convert this dataframe into `.tocoo()` matrix and `.tolil()`?

Reference how `combined` column is formed from 
Original Pandas DataFrame:

`import pandas as pd` `pd.DataFrame` `({0:[28,32,36,37,84],1: [1,1,1,1,1], 2: [1,1,1,1,1]})`. col 0 has over 10K unique features, `col 1` has 39 groups and `col 2` is just 1.

Comment: Have you read the `sparse.coo_matrix` docs?

Comment: little bit but cant make sense

Comment: What are the elements (cells) of that series? strings?  They look like the *display* of a coo matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj - those are constructs from a columns of pandas dataframe:  pd.DataFrame({0:[28,32,36,37,84],1: [1,1,1,1,1], 2: [1,1,1,1,1]}), column '1' has 39 unique elements. Column '0' has 10K. 'combined' is a concat of three columns- with tuple of col 0 and col 1.

Comment: I suspect the original dataframe columns are more useful than the combined.  They look like the arrays that can be used as the `row, col` and `data` parameters to `coo_matrix`.

Comment: okay this might be it. take a look into of solutions below for coo_matrix

Comment: @hpaulj - thanks again, I have a question below regarding `lil matrix`

Answer (score 1):

**`Formation of COOrdinate format from original pandas DataFrame`**

```
    import scipy.sparse as sps

    groups.set_index([0, 1], inplace=True)
    sps.coo_matrix((groups[2], (groups.index.labels[0], groups.index.labels[1])))
```

-------------Results to---------

```
<10312x39 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 14476 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Comment: That's what I expect.  A `print` of that matrix would look a lot like the `(i,j) d` column you  initially showed - but with a lot more values.

Comment: Once you have the `coo` format you can use `tolil()` to make a `lil` format.  But do you need it?  `coo` is good for constructing a matrix as you've done. `lil` is useful of filling in values one by one, but I don't think you need that.  `csr` is used for most calculations.

Comment: I am working with graph data so need `lil`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why should there be a better way?  Your source naturally feeds a `coo` format.  Developers have tried to do a good job of writing the converters.   Use them.

Answer (score 0):

**`In regards to lil matrix`**

```
print(len(networks[0]), len(networks[1]), networks[0].nunique(), networks[1].nunique())
667966 667966 10312 10312
networks[:5]

    0   1
0   176 1
1   233 1
2   283 1
3   371 1
4   394 1


# make row and col labels
rows = networks[0]
cols = networks[1]

# crucial third array in python
networks.set_index([0, 1], inplace=True)
Ntw= sps.coo_matrix((networks[2], (networks.index.labels[0], 
networks.index.labels[1])))


d=Ntw.tolil()
d
```

**generates**

```
   <10312x10312 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 667966 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

Comment: shape of `d` should be the same as `ones`

Comment: I'm betting `networks[0]` and `networks[1]` are not zero-indexed, but the `coo_matrix` will always be